# Streamline if statements

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have several if statements ike the one below. Am assuming that this is a really bad/ long handed way of coding but not sure what I should be doing differently. Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks

```
For a = 1 To Leagues
     If a = 1 Then
    SheetName = "E0"
    ElseIf a = 2 Then
        SheetName = "E1"
     ElseIf a = 3 Then
        SheetName = "E2"
      ElseIf a = 4 Then
        SheetName = "E3"
       ElseIf a = 5 Then
        SheetName = "EC"
        ElseIf a = 6 Then
            SheetName = "SC0"
         ElseIf a = 7 Then
            SheetName = "SC1"
          ElseIf a = 8 Then
            SheetName = "SC2"
           ElseIf a = 9 Then
            SheetName = "SC3"
            ElseIf a = 10 Then
                SheetName = "D1"
             ElseIf a = 11 Then
                SheetName = "D2"
              ElseIf a = 12 Then
                SheetName = "SP1"
               ElseIf a = 13 Then
                SheetName = "SP2"
                ElseIf a = 14 Then
                    SheetName = "I1"
                 ElseIf a = 15 Then
                    SheetName = "I2"
                  ElseIf a = 16 Then
                    SheetName = "F1"
                   ElseIf a = 17 Then
                    SheetName = "F2"
                    ElseIf a = 18 Then
                        SheetName = "N1"
                     ElseIf a = 19 Then
                        SheetName = "B1"
                      ElseIf a = 20 Then
                        SheetName = "P1"
                       ElseIf a = 21 Then
                        SheetName = "T1"
                        ElseIf a = 22 Then
                        SheetName = "G1"
    End If
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Yes `Select Case` is probably what you are after.

Comment: And I have never seen someone indent every `Else If`. That's...interesting.

Comment: @John, Added a method using a datafield array which allows you to use a one liner to assign the wanted sheet name.

Comment: @T.M. Thanks - that looks even better as I don't need to hardcode the sheet names  - and I'm guessing it's simpler code. Just need to work out how to reference a separate workbook in the code rather than 'ThisWorkbook' - struggling with that since moving to excel Mac. Appreciate you taking the time to answer

Comment: Use `Workbooks`(index), where *index* is the workbook name (or index number), to return a single Workbook object. You have to use `Set` for assigning it to an object variable, e.g. `Dim oWb As Workbook` and `Set oWb = Workbooks("MyWorkbookName")`; then you get the workbook name via `oWb.Name`. See MS help at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224504(v=office.11).aspx  - *Attention*: don't confound WorkBook as type and the `Workbooks` property.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No `If` or `Case` needed using a datafield array**

You could store all your sheet names listed in a work sheet to a one based 2-dim datafield array. This allows you to get the nth sheetname by one code line: `SheetName = v(n, 1)` (or `SheetName = v(a, 1)` as in your example).

```
Sub test()
Dim a         As Integer
Dim sheetname As String
Dim v         ' variant, receives 2-dim data field contents
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheetNameList") ' << change to sheet where you store your sheet names
' create one based 2-dim datafield array from your sheetname list
' (assuming start in cell A2, omitting title row)
  v = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
' ... example value for a
  a = 22
' assign sheet name avoiding any IF, CASE or SWITCH
  sheetname = v(a, 1)       ' get e.g. 22nd item (
  Debug.Print a, sheetname
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are comparing multiple options to a single variant (in your case `a`), it is much simpler while also improving readability by using `Select Case` rather than `If...Then`.

Take a look:

```
Sub test()

    Select Case a
        Case 1
            SheetName = "E0"
        Case 2
            SheetName = "E1"
        Case 3
            SheetName = "E2"
        Case 4
            SheetName = "E3"
        Case 5
            SheetName = "EC"
        Case 6
            SheetName = "SC0"
        Case 7
            SheetName = "SC1"
        Case 8
            SheetName = "SC2"
        Case 9
            SheetName = "SC3"
        Case 10
            SheetName = "D1"
        Case 11
            SheetName = "D2"
        Case 12
            SheetName = "SP1"
        Case 13
            SheetName = "SP2"
        Case 14
            SheetName = "I1"
        Case 15
            SheetName = "I2"
        Case 16
            SheetName = "F1"
        Case 17
            SheetName = "F2"
        Case 18
            SheetName = "N1"
        Case 19
            SheetName = "B1"
        Case 20
            SheetName = "P1"
        Case 21
            SheetName = "T1"
        Case 22
            SheetName = "G1"
    End Select

End Sub
```

I should probably add that `Select Case` can also be used in this syntax as well *(wouldn't work in your instance, but something to keep in mind in the future)*:

```
Select Case a
    Case 1 To 5
        sheetname = "E0"
    Case 6, 8 To 9
        sheetname = "E1"
    Case 7
        sheetname = "E2"
    Case Else
        sheetname = "Blah"
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks - really appreciated.